# redirect non www to www with .htaccess in yii

Tags: php, apache, http, yii

this is my .htacess :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

i want to redirect non www requests to www.example.com but when i add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

i get 404 error for my css and js and other files now  , all of file requests goes to yii controllers

Framework : yii2

Php 5.4

Apache :2.4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this answer :

```
RewriteEngine on

#non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^adnasor\.ir 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.adnasor.ir/$1 [R=301,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```